# Fancybox moves centred divs

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox, fancybox-2

I've got one div `(#div2)` within another `(#div1)` on my webpage that misbehaves when the Fancybox content is loaded: it's being moved to the right side of the browser while the rest of the page is displayed correctly.

Any help?

simplified structure of the **html** code:

```
<body>
    <div id="div1">
        <div id="div2">
            ...div content here...
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**css** codes for the divs:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

#div1{
    height: 90px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#div2{
    height: 90px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 980px;
}
```

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle or codepen demo?

Comment: We would need to see your actual body code -- is your #div2 nested inside the #div1 tag or are they siblings?

Comment: Please check the code I have just added. Hope it is enough as it would take a lot of time for me to make it working on **jsfiddle** etc.

Comment: There is a big discussion (and workarounds) about the issue here https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/360

Comment: I do know about that discussion ;)
I read through it already - didn't find it helpful though...